# How to remove single item in database from a listbox?

Tags: c#, sql

How to remove single item in database?
When I click on remove button my code removes all items that are same as the selectedItem in listbox. e.g If I choose to remove CocaCola from my listbox I want that it removes that single CocaCola item in database not all CocaCola items.

my code:

```
conn.Open();
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("delete from Products Where Product ='"+lstProducts.SelectedItem+"'", conn);
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
conn.Close();
```

Comment: Do you just want to delete an arbitrary record where the product is CocaCola?

Comment: If I have 10 cocacola items in database list and I click remove I want it to remove only one cocacola item not all of them.

Comment: [SQL Injection alert](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms161953%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) - you should **not** concatenate together your SQL statements - use **parametrized queries** instead to avoid SQL injection

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it doesn't matter which rows remain you can use `TOP(1)`:

```
DELETE TOP (1)
FROM  Products 
Where Product = @Product
```

Note that you should use sql parameters instead of string concatanation to prevent sql injection and other less serious issues.

[MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189835.aspx):

> **When TOP is used with DELETE, the referenced rows are not arranged in
>   any order** and the ORDER BY clause can not be directly specified in
>   this statement. If you need to use TOP to delete rows in a meaningful
>   chronological order, you must use TOP together with an ORDER BY clause
>   in a subselect statement. See the Examples section that follows in
>   this topic. TOP cannot be used in a DELETE statement against
>   partitioned views.

Acc. to the [`TOP(1)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189463(v=sql.120).aspx):

> For backward compatibility, the parentheses are optional in SELECT
>   statements. We recommend that you always use parentheses for TOP in
>   SELECT statements for consistency with **its required use in INSERT,
>   UPDATE, MERGE, and DELETE statements in which the parentheses are
>   required**.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to use TOP like this:

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("delete top (1) from Products Where Product ='"+lstProducts.SelectedItem+"'", conn);
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Also your code is prone to SQL Injection. You can use parameterized query to get rid of it.

Comment: You have to use `TOP (1)`

Answer (score 1):

For this behavior you need to have Product column with foreign key Unique, otherwise you need to pass the ID or another unique column.

Comment: note that sql removes all the rows for matching criteria, using top will remove the first one, not the desired one.